# Saving Fragment State on Back Button Select

Tags: android, fragment, back-button

I'm so very confused and have been reading on this topic for a while.

I have a MainActivity that has multiple possible contents (switched between via navigation drawer), which I've set via multiple fragments (lets call them Fragment1, Fragment2 and Fragment3).

That works fine.

One of my fragments, Fragment3, is a View that can segue to a new activity, View2.

View2 has a back button. When I press on the View2 back button I want to see Fragment3 on my MainActivity, not Fragment1, which is what I currently get. This is because OnCreate, by default, loads Fragment1.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks so much in advance! (vent: iOS makes this so much easier).

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for Fragments states that you should make sure to call addToBackStack() before commiting your fragment transaction on your first activity holding the 3 fragments. 
In order to go back to the last used fragment from the second activity , you should override the onBackPressed() method in this activity :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

The documentation is very complete on the subject : [Read it here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I just added this to the back button code:

```
finish();
return true;
```

I had to do it within onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)... for some reason onBackPressed is not fired.